# Is there a way i can set dynamic log file name in log4j.properties?

Tags: selenium, log4j2

I have a logger in each of my test class. What i want to do is generate separate log file for each of my test class. Is there a way i can pass a file name to log4j2.properties in my BeforeClass method? I am trying below but its not working:

This is my log4j2.properties file:

```
name=PropertiesConfig
property.myLogs
property.filename = logs
appenders = console, file

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = LOGFILE
appender.file.fileName=${filename}/${myLogs}.log  #I AM TRYING TO PASS DYNAMIC value in 'myLogs' variable.
appender.file.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

rootLogger.level = trace
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRefs = LOGFILE
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = LOGFILE
```

Trying to set the "property.myLogs" in my BeforeMethod but its not generating the log file as "logs.log":

```
Properties config =  new Properties();
FileInputStream propertiesFile = new FileInputStream("D:\\Automation\\src\\main\\resources\\log4j2.properties");
config.load(propertiesFile);
System.setProperty("property.myLogs", "logs");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
appender.file.fileName=${sys:logDir}/${sys:logFile}.log
```

then in your beforeClass method do:

```
System.setProperty("logDir", "logs");
System.setProperty("logFile", "log");
```

Answer (score 0):

Configure your logger in @BeforeClass programmatically - set new appender. in @AterClass close the file